# How to import dynamic v-bind:is component with module system in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps

**Problem:** I am trying to programmatically register a component to be used in a slot in my Vue/Nuxt site. The component name is included in the data of the parent `index.vue` file, in this instance the component is named `Projects`. I am including it in a `v-for` template as the various objects in the `'modules'` data array are iterated over. I had assumed this would be possible/easy from the [dynamic component documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) and [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-dynamic-components) however I have not managed to get it working in my case.

**What I expect to happen:** I expected the component to be registered and 'slotted' into the `Module` component correctly.

**What actually happens:** While I can see on the rendered view that the component is 'there', it is not in the correct place (i.e. slotted into the `Module` component). I also get a `vue/no-unused-components` error saying: `The "Projects" component has been registered but not used`.

I have read the documentation about [component registration in modular systems](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Module-Systems) but these seem to be for more complex cases than what I am trying to achieve. Any advice would be really helpful as I am totally stuck!

`index.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="module in modules">
      <Module
        :title="module.title"
        :to="module.link"
      />
      <component v-bind:is="module.slot" />
      </Module>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Module from '~/components/module/Module.vue'
import Projects from '~/components/module/slots/Projects.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    Module,
    Projects
  },
  data () {
    return {
      modules: [
        {
          title: 'Work',
          slot: 'Projects'
        },
        {
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Edit:** As a side note, I get the same error when registering the component with `import` like so:

```
components: {
  Module,
  'Projects': () => import('@/components/module/slots/Projects')
}
```

`Module.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>
      {{ title }}
    </h2>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`Projects.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Projects</h3>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Projects'
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the self closure tag in your `Module` component.

This prevents your `Projects` component to be rendered within the slot.

Just replace:

```html
<Module
   :title="module.title"
    :to="module.link"
/>
```

with:

```html
<Module
   :title="module.title"
    :to="module.link"
>
```

and it should work.

Comment: A typo ‍♂️ – classic! Thank you so much, good to know I was understanding OK!